# How to use different java versions for different programs?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, java, jdk6

This may be common in web but may be I am not getting what to search exactly. Actually I am having different versions of java on my ubuntu server having java 1.5 as default. One of my program need java 1.6 and even if I perform following in the shell script executing that program

`export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk6`
I dont get any success.What I learnt is I could see current java version using 

`java -version`
This only get change when I changes the alternative using:

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Please tell me how can I change it in the shell script which in turn calls the java program requiring java6 having java 5 as default only.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `PATH` as well:

```
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk6
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
```